# Fluent Nhibernate endless cycle

Tags: c#, windows, forms, nhibernate, fluent

There is no exeption.Just wanna know is it well or not.

Medicine Map:

```
    public MedicineMap()
     {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Date);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Companies).Cascade.All();
       }
```

Company Map:

```
    public CompanyMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.CompanyName);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Medicines).Cascade.All();
    }
```

When im trying to get "medicines" from base it is returned me endless cycle.
like this :

[image]

So there are medicine filed in company and conversely company field in medicine endlessly.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: There is no exeption.Just wanna know is it well or not.

Comment: this is not nhibernate specific. If you have two objects referencing each other, there will always be such endless chains. Nothing wrong in it.

Answer (score 0):

whenever I have a Many-To-Many relationship, I always had the **Inverse()** to one of the Maps and I define the name of the intermediate table in case you need to call it. Your code would stay like this:

```
public MedicineMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.Name);
    Map(x => x.Date);
    HasManyToMany(x => x.Companies)
        .Cascade.All()
        .Inverse()
        .Table("MedicineCompany");
}
```

and

```
public CompanyMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Map(x => x.CompanyName);
    HasManyToMany(x => x.Medicines)
        .Cascade.All()
        .Table("MedicineCompany");
}
```

Does this solve your problem?

If not, please share your code where you try to return the medicine, maybe we can help you there, in order not to receive an infinite cycle.